# Bracha on jalapeño peppers?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

The Bracha on onions and garlic eaten raw is shehakol since its not the usual way to eat onions or garlic raw. Do we say that jalapeños are also shehakol when eaten raw according to the same logic?

Comment: Is it usual to eat jalapenos raw or not? Maybe ask over on [cooking.se]. Should we migrate?

Comment: I agree and follow up w/ @DoubleAA on this. I assume that in your question, you are eating an olive's size of jalapeno which would require the beginning bracha. In the U.S., it is not usual for people to eat raw jalapeno, so I guess this would require *shehakol*. In Mexico, and, maybe India, where this is more common, people there would say *ha'adama*, but I believe you follow the custom of where you came from, not where you are if you're a guest.

Comment: @DanF http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65629/759

Answer (score 3):

I have a friend whose wife is from Mexico. He once told me that in a shiur (class) given in Spanish by Rav Vaia he said that for them the bracha is *ha'adama*, since they are used to very spicy foods, but for most people it would be *shehakol*. The thing is, I heard this secondhand, and I don't know whether he was joking or giving a *psak*.

Answer (score 1):

Halachapedia [quotes](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot_On_Foods_That_Start_With_The_Letter_H)  Yalkut Yosef (Klalei Sefer Brachot pg 208-214) who writes the beracha on a raw hot pepper if you enjoy it is shehakol.